# Why the following code changing the tree view node icon in WPF not working?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I had created a TreeView with my custom class as follows in WPF:

Class definition:

```
    public class FileTreeItem
    {
        public FileTreeItem() // For root item
        {
            Icon = new WriteableBitmap(1, 1, 72, 72, PixelFormats.Rgb24, null);
            ItemText = "";
            Items = new ObservableCollection<FileTreeItem>();
            ParentNode = this;
        }
        public FileTreeItem(FileTreeItem parentNode) // For other items.
        {
            Icon = new WriteableBitmap(1, 1, 72, 72, PixelFormats.Rgb24, null);
            ItemText = "";
            Items = new ObservableCollection<FileTreeItem>();
            ParentNode = parentNode;
        }
        public ObservableCollection<FileTreeItem> Items { get; set; }
        public ImageSource Icon { get; set; }
        public string ItemText { get; set; }
        
        public NodeType NodeType
        {
            get => _nodeType;
            set
            {
                _nodeType = value;
                Icon = _nodeType switch
                {
                    NodeType.File => SharedRes.FileIcon, // See below for SharedRes definition
                    NodeType.Folder => SharedRes.FolderIcon,
                    _ => Icon
                };
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ItemText;
        }
        public bool IsExpanded { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
        public FileTreeItem ParentNode { get; }
        private NodeType _nodeType;
    }
```

And here's the SharedRes class definition, it's basically a class that loads the resources icons in "Resource.resx" and convert it to a bitmap source:

```
public static class SharedRes
{
    public static BitmapSource FolderIcon
    {
        get { return _folderIcon ??= GetBitmapFromIcon("Shell_Folder"); }
    }

    public static BitmapSource FileIcon
    {
        get { return _fileIcon ??= GetBitmapFromIcon("Shell_File"); }
    }

    private static BitmapSource GetBitmapFromIcon(string IconName)
    {
        Uri folder_path = new Uri($"pack://application:,,,/{IconName}.ico");
        using var ms = new MemoryStream(Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(IconName) as byte[] ?? Array.Empty<byte>());
        IconBitmapDecoder decoder = new IconBitmapDecoder(ms, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat,
            BitmapCacheOption.None);
        return decoder.Frames[0].Clone();
    }

    private static BitmapSource? _folderIcon;
    private static BitmapSource? _fileIcon;
}
```

Here's the tree view template, you can see the Image is binding to Icon property in the FileTreeItem class:

```
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FileTreeItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Image MaxWidth="16" MaxHeight="16" Width="16" Height="16" Source="{Binding Icon}" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemText, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

Now, if I do this thing in the main window code, with a node already selected:

```
    this_node.NodeType = this_node.NodeType == NodeType.File ? NodeType.Folder : NodeType.File; // It went wrong here.
```

The binded Icon property changed, but the image that's showing in the screen does not.

I can confirm that every time the Icon property changed, it was assigned with different value every time I try to change the `NodeType` property. I've also tried to use other ways to set the `Icon` property directly (even by directly forcing the value when running), but none of them works.

Please note that this is not about "How to use INotifyProperty" interface.

Comment: The ItemsSource binding is to Items which is an observable collection, in order to fire a refresh the observable collection must be renewed.  Just adding a single item or removing is not enough.

Comment: You'd need a datatrigger to switch your icon out based on a bound value. And you would need to have a viewmodel implements inotifypropertychanged and raised property change .

Comment: In your GetBitmapFromIcon method you should also use BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad and drop the Clone() call.

Comment: I'd also suggest exploring vector formats rather than ico. I like path and geometry myself but drawing brush if you want multiple colours.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event each time the `Node` property is set to a new value:

```
public class FileTreeItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...

    private ImageSource _icon;
    public ImageSource Icon
    {
        get { return _icon; }
        set { _icon = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```